# ZF2 : How to dynamically connect to database (without global.php)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

my ZF2 application have to connect to different MSSQL databases (about 3000 !)
so i cant prepare all connections.
(i dont connect to all DB of course, it depends on the user query).

How can i do that, within a controller ?
(only the DB name changes, server and user are always the same)

thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend thats, but you can use the pdo / mysqli / .. object in jours controllers to connect on other databases.

$dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

// Else you can create multiple service to access to your databases.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
//...
$driver = array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=yourdatabasename;host=yourdatabasehost',             
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
);
$adapter = new Adapter($driver);

//insert into database
$adapter->query("insert into foo(bar) values('foo value')",Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

//select from database        
$result = $adapter->query('select * from foo',Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
foreach ($result as $item)
    print_r((array)$item);
```

you can pass this `$adapter` to a `TableGateway` and prepare a table Model (for example YourModule\Model\FooTable).

Comment: you're welcome. Since you are new here, please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).